# requirements for running a play app on a server

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm developing a web application for a company using the play framework. Their IT department has probably some restrictions (which I don't know yet). I want to talk to them about the deployment of my play app on their servers but I'm not really familiar with these things. So can anyone help me and give me some information about the requirements for running a play app on a server? (things that they have to support in order to run my app)

I know that a JDK version of 6 or above is required. is there anything else? I would appreciate your answers

Ps: I'm developing using play 2.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can talk about the following things :

1. Database (if they only support PostgreSQL for example you have to use it)
2. Ports : Play uses by default the port 9000, you have to tell them to open it

You have to choose how you will deploy your app : https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production.
For example, if you start the application from the project, you need to install Activator.
If they defined strict rules on the firewall, you need to tell them to open ports accordingly in order to download the dependencies.